# Don't specify width & height constraints on my UIView (like UILabel can do)

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

If I put a UILabel in a view and specify a vertical space constraint and an horizontal space constraint, it's fine.

If I do the same with my custom UIView, IB will complain because it'll lack an height and a width constraints.

I guess it comes from the fact that UILabel can expand both vertically and horizontally. But so does my custom UIView, so how can I inform that my view has such rights?

Comment: Please show how you add vertical and horizontal space constraints. I think you for some reason they don't get added to you label and your view.

Comment: @dasdom : I simply ctrl-drag from my label to its superview and choose 'Top space to container' and 'Leading space to container'

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for a UILabel is "Fit To Content"(Editor-> Fit To Content). This means that UILabel will grow as the Content increases for a given font size. For a view to position itself, it needs X, Y, Width and Height. Width and Height are given by the text it contains. Rest two properties you have already provided. I hope that answers your question.